# Перенаправление ввода со стороны сервера

Tags: c#, asp.net, сервер, client

Есть задача: написание кода в браузере и компиляция на стороне сервера. Допустим, в коде есть запрос ввода от пользователя. Так как код выполняется на стороне сервера, как перенаправить запрос ввода в браузер? Подскажите, пожалуйста, от чего отталкиваться и каким методом лучше решить данную задачу.

Comment: "в коде есть запрос ввода от пользователя" - ? В каком виде? `Console.ReadLine`, `textbox1.Text`?

Comment: @Igor , в виде `Console.ReadLine`

Comment: Если необходимо читать ввод от пользователя, то код все таки придется выполнять на клиенте. Текущая архитектура плохо подходит под поставленную задачу.

Comment: У Вас не консольная программа. `Console.ReadLine` там не к месту.

Comment: @Igor Вы немного не поняли, что я хочу. Можно представить проект как Web ide. Пишет пользователь код, в коде есть запрос на ввод - как реализовать?